# Using multiple NHibernate listeners which make database updates?

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate 2.1 in and have some listeners that implement IPreInsertEventListener, IPreUpdateEventListener, IPreDeleteEventListener.

Two of the listeners perform last minute database operations. Both are audit related, but perform very different audit operations, hence separate listeners - one listener audits everything and writes to an audit table, the other is interested in just a handful of entity types and updates data in a different table.

The problem I have is that after creating or updating my audit entities and saving them to the session, the listeners in turn try to flush the session, which triggers another update and before long I get a StackOverflowException.

Here's an example of what the two different listeners are doing:

```
// Generic audit listener (audits everything)
public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent evnt)
{
    // Ignore audit entries, otherwise we go round and round
    if (!(evnt.Entity == AuditEntry))
    {
        ISession session = evnt.Session.GetSession(EntityMode.Poco);
        // create AuditEntry for the updated Entity
        // ...
        session.Save(auditEntity);
        session.Flush();
    }
}

// Restricted audit listener (only interested in a handful of entities)
public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent evnt)
{
    if (evnt.Entity is RelevantToThisListener) // etc
    {
        ISession session = evnt.Session.GetSession(EntityMode.Poco);
        // create or modify some other audit entity
        // ...
        session.Save(auditEntity);
        session.Flush();
    }
}
```

One thought is to have just 1 audit listener that delegates tasks appropriately and is responsible for one single flush.

But before going down that route, are there other alternatives? Is it possible to start another isolated session of this event session so that I am flushing only the new changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: `var isolatedSession = evnt.Session.Factory.OpenSession();`

Option 2: remove `session.Flush();` from the listeners

i would favor Option 2 because

- would enable batching for audit rows, which the immediate Flush breaks
- audit rows would also be rolled back when the audited entities are rolled back

Comment: Thanks. Option 2 does not work for me, as with no flush, the new entities are not written to the database on commit, any ideas why?  However Option 1 does work perfectly.

Comment: Actually, Option 1 doesn't work for me, as the Flush does indeed break the roll back of audit row.  So it would be helpful to find out why Option 2 does not work.

Comment: It doesn't flush on Commit if you specified `FlushMode.Never` otherwise it will always flush on Commit. Maybe you are commiting on the wrong session or your entities haven't changed